# Strange behavior with ggplot, sf package and orthographic projection

Tags: r, sf, ggplot2

Cross posting with stack-overflow: the ggplot package throws errors for some versions of an orthographic projection. For example, this works fine

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

data("World") ## get built-in data from the tmap package
world.sf <- World
projection <- "+proj=ortho +lat_0=40"
# Fix polygons so they don't get cut in ortho projection
ortho_world.sf  <- st_cast(world.sf, 'MULTILINESTRING') %>%
  st_cast('LINESTRING', do_split=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(npts = npts(geometry, by_feature = TRUE)) %>%
  st_cast('POLYGON') %>% st_transform(crs=projection)
ggplot() + geom_sf(data=ortho_world.sf)
```

This projection works as well

```
projection <- "+proj=ortho +lat_0=70 +lon_0=-181" ## works fine
```

But all of these throw errors

```
projection <- "+proj=ortho +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-180" ## throws error
projection <- "+proj=ortho +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-149" ## throws error
projection <- "+proj=ortho +lat_0=20 +lon_0=-149" ## throws error
```

The error seems to be in sf, since I get similiar problems with plot in base R. What's going on?

Comment: What error? You should always show the error message, and also try and minimise your example to just enough code to generate the error. Also, where does `npts` come from and is that line necessary to generate the error?

Comment: Another good thing to do when you get an error related to projection of a large number of features is to break it down - try one feature, if that works, try half of the features, if that fails then keep halving until you may discover one feature that fails and then work out what's pathological about it - maybe its a polygon with only a single point or something, and then eliminate all those from your features and use that...

Comment: Solution posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77298627/strange-behavior-with-ggplot-sf-package-and-orthographic-projection. Yes, it was st_cast("POLYGON") on objects with less than 3 points